# Python extract properties from list of listed objects

Tags: python, list, properties

I have list of assembly class instances.  The total number of assemblies in the list can change.

```
ASM_list = [ASM1,ASM2,ASM3...etc]
```

each assembly has a list of parts (I have filtered the assemblies to all have the same parts)

```
ASM1.parts = ['hood','fender','door']
ASM2.parts = ['hood','fender','door']
```

each part has properties

```
ASM1.parts[0].color = green
ASM2.parts[0].color = blue
```

I would like to print out part properties for each assembly.  Example output:

```
part, ASM1, ASM2, ASM3
hood, green, blue, red
fender, black, red, yellow
door, yellow, green, orange
```

I'm having trouble using zip or map to do this.

An example of what I'm trying below.

```
parts_list = []
for ASM in ASM_list:
  parts_list.append([p.color for p in ASM.parts])
print zip(*parts_list)
```

The "Python cookbook" and several other stack overflow posts show how to iterate through multiple list at the same time, the problem I have is that the number of assemblies changes so I can't write:

```
for a,b,c in ASM_lists:
  a.part.color, b.part.color, c.part.color
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a list of `part_names` - which, if your part objects objects have a `name` attribute as well as a `color` attribute, you could get by:

```
part_names = []
for part in ASM_list[0].parts:
    part_names.append(part.name)
```

Then you can get the output you want with:

```
headers = ["part"]
for i, ASM in enumerate(ASM_list):
    headers.append("ASM%d" % (i+1))
print(", ".join(headers))

for i, part_colors in enumerate(zip(*parts_list)):
    part_name = part_names[i]
    print(part_name + ", " + ", ".join(part_colors))
```

Comment: I greatly appreciate your insight.  I don't fully grasp all of it yet, as of now I'm getting an "expected string, float found" error on the final print statement.  I tried str(part_name) to no avail.

Comment: This works... The failures comes from me using this pattern on part properties that are floats (part dimensions).  Maybe with some tuple formatting it will be reusable?

Comment: " ".join(map(str, a)) converts to a string for join.   THANKS!